# Network Exception thrown after session timeout

Tags: networking, database, web-applications

My site will run fine and I can go through the entire site, but after my session times out, when I make another request to a page I get this exception:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The system cannot find the file specified
Description: An un-handled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +907
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +334
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +443
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +359
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32() +426
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +77
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +174
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +552
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +90
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +171
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +151
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +91
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +53
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +33
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +26
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id) +49
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +166
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<b__1>d__4.MoveNext() +904
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.d__2.MoveNext() +2200
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +571
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +255
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +404
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +404
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +404
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext() +180
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0

---

At this point the site will not function until I delete my application cookie.  I will continue to get the network exception on all page requests.  i don't understand how i could be connecting just fine to my database then all of a sudden stop being able to connect to it. Its like a connection to the database went stale and is not able to re-establish.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that you need to install SQL Server Express  and enable the Local Database Runtime feature

```
Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.  It turns out that the ApplicationDbContext connection string was not set on the Publish settings configuration.  I had another dbcontext that was the main one used by the application and it was set.  This is why the application work fine at first.  There must be something in the Session Time out process that calls into the ApplicationDbContext which caused the exception I was experiencing.  Can someone explain what that could be?